# WebRequest.GetResponse() over SSL

Tags: asp.net, ssl, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am having trouble calling an SSRS report server over SSL. I cannot figure out whether the issue is with my code or the configuration of either my web site or the SSRS site (both are under my control).

Below is some background. I am providing as much information as I can, because I don't know where the problem is. Some of it may not be relevant.

1. Web site (ASP.NET 4.0) and SSRS (2008 R2) are running on same server.
2. Everything works fine when both are running using http/port 80
3. Error returned by the SSRS url is "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
4. Certificate is fine, just created and installed it.
5. Certificate specified under https binding in IIS, and under SSL info for SSRS.
6. Web site uses anonymous authentication.
7. Application Pool Identity of web site is same domain user as SSRS service account. This same user is assigned to the "Browser" role in SSRS.
8. I have tried opening the HTTPS URL both with and without specify port 443
9. SSRS URL uses same sub domain as web site and both match the certificate
10. In my code, before calling GetResponse, I set Credentials to CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials. Also tried DefaultNetworkCredentials and leaving that line of code completely out.
11. Even though SSRS is running on the same server as the web site, I cannot "see" the SSRS site in IIS (seems weird and a mystery I haven't been able to solve). I do not see more than one version of IIS installed.
12. Nothing in SSRS logs (nothing, no indication that SSRS ever even got the request)

My intuition says this is a configuration setting somewhere, rather than a code issue, but I cannot figure it out. I've read a little about impersonation and wondering if that is what I need. I'd rather not bypass certificate validation unless that is the proper approach in circumstances such as this. If this is the problem, I want to do it properly.

Comment: Update: I added a callback to unconditionally accept the certificate and am still  getting a 401 error. Going to try to figure out why SSRS is not showing in IIS admin.

Comment: I learned the SSRS 2008 R2 does not run inside IIS. I tried something else afterwards that also did not work (same 401 error): req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain); I added this before opening the response stream. At this point, I am running out of ideas, can anyone help?